# Why is IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext sometimes null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpcontext, delegatinghandler

Using .Net Core 2.2, I'm using HttpClient to call an API, along with an Http Message Handler.  The message handler injects `IHttpContextAccessor`, but that object sometimes contains an `HttpContext` property that is null - I can't understand why that would ever be null.

Here's the service registration in startup:

```
services.AddTransient<HttpClientTokenHandler>();

services.AddHttpClient("client", c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri(options.ApiUrl.TrimEnd('/') + '/');
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientTokenHandler>();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And the token handler implementation where HttpContext is sometimes null.

```
public HttpClientTokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
    _context = context;
}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
    var access_token = await _context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(Constants.TokenTypes.AccessToken);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
    }
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}
```

What could cause `_context.HttpContext` to be null, when it's simply being injected?

Comment: Just for clarification, is `_context` null? Or the property `HttpContext` null?

Comment: @mxmissile only the ```HttpContext``` property is null, ```_context``` is not null

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` is only available if you call `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in `ConfigureServices`, which your code isn't doing.

Comment: @IanKemp fair point, i pared down the startup and failed to put that in the question.  thanks for catching that.

Comment: @JeremyMaddrey I have exactly this problem

Comment: Same problem for me, I forgot to call  services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); in one of the microservices, thanks @IanKemp